# UITableView cell takes pattern color of UITableView's background image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I've added custom background image to my UITableView and it shows fine. Than, i removed any background color from the cells. Now i expect to see only cells' text on top of table's background image, however i see strange behaviour. Cells take pattern color of table's background image, so that i see waves like in the picture:

[image]

The background image shell look like this:

[image]

*pay attention to white circles that disappear under the cells!

My code is as follws:
in viewDidLoad i set the background image of table view:

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"general_bg.png"]];
```

For each cell i remove any background color like this:

```
UIView *bckView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
bckView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.backgroundView = bckView;

cell.backgoundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UILabel *textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,x1,y1)];
textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview:textLabel];
```

- line separators are custom images added to cells.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of setting the BackgroundColor attribute of the tableview, try setting the backgroundview:

```
UIView *background = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.bounds];
background.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR_IMAGE.png"]];
self.tableView.backgroundView = background;
```

This should fix the issue of the cell's taking on the same image as the background.

Comment: But what if someone actually wants tableview back color to be a pattern, without having that pattern repeat for the cells?

Comment: Small suggestion. Now, in 2013, don't use magic numbers.
`UIView *background = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.bounds];`

Answer (score 0):

```
self.tableView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR_IMAGE.png"]];
```

maybe this is what you're looking for